# Search SQL and return true or false

Tags: sql

I have a table that has thousands of rows in. I need to check if certain values exists in the table or not.

I want to list all the bar codes I am searching with a flag of true or false returned if there is one.

I have come up with this so far:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE Coulmn in ('a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')
)
THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END
```

This however just returns a value of 1.

So in the table I have

```
coulmn
----------
A
B
D
E
F
G
```

I want to do a search that returns the following

```
Coulmn | Exsists
-----------------
A      |  True
B      |  True
C      |  False
D      |  True
E      |  True
F      |  True
G      |  True
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result!

Comment: I didn't understand, you want 1 to become True and 0 to become False? If it's what you want SQL Server does not work with True or False but bit 1 and 0. If you want True or False they will have to be VARCHARs.

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @jarlh Updated, hope this helps

Comment: @caiohamamura added some data

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You need a help table with all possible bar codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help form above I created a temp table and then implemented one of the soultions shared.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
       Barcode VARCHAR (100)
)
INSERT INTO #Temp
VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4 )
select barcode, case when exists 
    (select * from CIPKORHHTProductDetails where CIPKORHHTProductDetails.Barcode = #temp.barcode)
    then 'True' else 'False' end as ExistsStatus
from #temp order by ExistsStatus DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN (Column in ('1','2')) THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END AS result_field
FROM TABLE;
```

NOTE: Tested in PostgreSQL

Comment: This does not work it returns 0 for all the rows. not 1 if present and 0 if not

Comment: It worked with my test table in PostgreSQL and in SQL Server as well.

In Oracle it worked with:

SELECT objectid, CASE WHEN (objectid in (1,2)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS result_field FROM cml_via_ln;

Comment: They want to see if, in your example, 1 and 2 exist in the data set... the response should be, for example,  1 TRUE, 2 FALSE.  This query does the opposite -- it lists all the things that are in the table and tells you whether or not they were what you were looking for; it's kind of inverted.  Close though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT t1.v,
       CASE WHEN t2.col IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS Exists
FROM (
   SELECT 'a' AS v UNION ALL SELECT 'b' UNION ALL SELECT 'c' UNION ALL SELECT 'd'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'e' UNION ALL SELECT 'f' UNION ALL SELECT 'g') AS t1
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.v = t2.col
```

Comment: I got thousands of items I need to query for so listing them all seperatly in a select may not be possible.

Comment: I suspect they just need an aggregate wrapping around the `CASE` to reduce the output to one row per `v` value.

Comment: @Legend1989 In that case you should consider populating a temp table with all the values you want to search and use this table in a query like the above.

Answer (score 0):

As it's written, the outer select is select case when exists () then 1 else 0 end... so it is only going to return one row.  The outer select must include "Column" AND "Exists" (select column, ...) to return two columns.

A "where" clause will never return a "false" like this, though, because "column" has to be in a real table for the query to actually return it.  As @jarlh says, you'll need a helper table to store the columns you're looking for:

```
Create table SearchColumns (SearchColumn char(1));
insert into SearchColumns (SearchColumn)
     values ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ('G'), ('H')
```

Then you can do the If Exists to your table from that table to see which values are in or not in:

```
select SearchColumn, case when exists 
    (select * from TABLE where Table.Column = SearchColumns.SearchColumn)
    then 'True' else 'False' end as ExistsStatus
from SearchColumns
```

I think that will get you what you want.  This gets a) Only one record per column no matter how many times it occurs in your table and b) "True" and "False" for every column value you're looking for.  If you really wanted a Bit, you can use 0 and 1 and the casting from the original query, but they actually show "0" and "1"; and c) this should work no matter how many values you have.

(Note, I assumed some of those were spelling errors, so I made adjustments, but they were consistent so I'm not certain).

Comment: The "SearchColumns" table could be temporary too, if you're into that sort of thing.